# From dotnet how to open file in containing folder in the Linux file manager?

Tags: .net, linux, explorer, finder

I'm developing a cross-platform application on dotnet with Avalonia UI and ReactiveUI.

I need to implement a command that open the file browser on the folder containing the file with the focus/highlight on the file.

Here is the command that works for Windows and OSX, but I don't know how to implement the case for Linux

```cs
    RevealInFolderCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask<string>(async path =>
        {
            if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
            {
                using Process fileOpener = new Process();
                fileOpener.StartInfo.FileName = "explorer";
                fileOpener.StartInfo.Arguments = "/select," + path + "\"";
                fileOpener.Start();
                await fileOpener.WaitForExitAsync();
            }
            else if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.OSX))
            {
                using Process fileOpener = new Process();
                fileOpener.StartInfo.FileName = "explorer";
                fileOpener.StartInfo.Arguments = "-R " + path;
                fileOpener.Start();
                await fileOpener.WaitForExitAsync();
            }
            else if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            else
            { 
                using Process fileOpener = new Process();
                fileOpener.StartInfo.FileName = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
                fileOpener.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                fileOpener.Start();
                await fileOpener.WaitForExitAsync();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When supported, dbus can provide that feature with this command line:

```
dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.FileManager1 /org/freedesktop/FileManager1 org.freedesktop.FileManager1.ShowItems array:string:"file:///some path/some file" string:""
```

Here is the code that handle the dbus case with a fallback to opening the folder:

```cs
        RevealInFolderCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask<string>(async path =>
        {
            if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
            {
                using Process fileOpener = new Process();
                fileOpener.StartInfo.FileName = "explorer";
                fileOpener.StartInfo.Arguments = "/select," + path + "\"";
                fileOpener.Start();
                await fileOpener.WaitForExitAsync();
                return;
            }
            if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.OSX))
            {
                using Process fileOpener = new Process();
                fileOpener.StartInfo.FileName = "explorer";
                fileOpener.StartInfo.Arguments = "-R " + path;
                fileOpener.Start();
                await fileOpener.WaitForExitAsync();
                return;
            }
            if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
            {
                using Process dbusShowItemsProcess = new Process
                {
                    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                    {
                        FileName = "dbus-send",
                        Arguments = "--print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.FileManager1 /org/freedesktop/FileManager1 org.freedesktop.FileManager1.ShowItems array:string:\"file://"+ path +"\" string:\"\"",
                        UseShellExecute = true
                    }
                };
                dbusShowItemsProcess.Start();
                await dbusShowItemsProcess.WaitForExitAsync();
    
                if (dbusShowItemsProcess.ExitCode == 0)
                {            
                    // The dbus invocation can fail for a variety of reasons:
                    // - dbus is not available
                    // - no programs implement the service,
                    // - ...
                    return;
                }
            }
            
            using Process folderOpener = new Process();
            folderOpener.StartInfo.FileName = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
            folderOpener.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            folderOpener.Start();
            await folderOpener.WaitForExitAsync();
        });
```